# After a good 4 months of W10, it has just started to restore to previous version. Why?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-update, downgrade

So I have been happily using W10 Home on my laptop for around 4 months and today I simply started it up, to find out a very warm christmasy welcome message saying "Restoring Windows to previous version". Why is this happening? I never requested a downgrade on it nor installed anything out of the ordinary. Nothing in fact. Anybody know about random W10 downgrades going on?

Comment: who else is using your computer (maybe you should not have left it running while Santa Claus was there...)?

Comment: Just me as far as I know